# python Pandas groupby on one column and display the number of occurrences of value counts per group along with values

Tags: python, pandas

New to pandas, tried different forums so ending up posting here for help.
I have a below dataframe

```
Dept Faculty
CSE AA
CSE AB
CSE AC
CSE AD
ECE BA
ECE AA
ECE BC
ECE BD
```

Trying to get something like this, i.e Faculty names along with total count per department

```
Dept Faculty    Count
CSE AA  4
    AB  
    AC  
    AD  
ECE BA  4
    AA  
    BC  
    BD
```

Trying `df.groupby('Dept')[Faculty].count()` gives count, but looking for Faculty names actual values column as well along with the count column

Can someone help?